# Issue with "Exceeded Data Storage" limit in one of my Salesforce Instance

Tags: database, salesforce, cloud, relational-database

I have an issue with "Exceeded Data Storage" limit in one of my **Salesforce Orgs**.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Buy additional data storage space from Salesforce.
2. Delete the unwanted data and archive the remaining data on a periodic basis
   on business needs in an **External Database**.
3. Provision to access the archived data from Salesforce whenever I want 
   to. This retrieval of data is just display of data in Salesforce

**My questions:**

1. There has to be code written in Salesforce for pushing data from Salesforce 
   to External Database during archival, but do we have to write code at the 
   database level as well to store and retrieve data?
2. If the answer is "No" can you suggest some affordable **cloud database** 
   options where this operation can be done seamlessly?

Comment: Why must there be code written in Salesforce for pushing data to an external database? As far as I know, salesforce expects you to retrieve the data and write it yourself to your own database of choice through whatever means it supports. Salesforce has provided tools for extracting data, but pushing to other databases is on you.

Answer (score 0):

1)How the external storage will knew about the fields that you want to export or about Salesforce fields at all...
Export it to csv from salesforce and create the extrenal storage objects by yourself. try to match it to salesforce fields as far as you can so if you will want to resore them it will be easy for you.

Regarding the options you mention,just a small clarification (option #1):
Do you know that there is two ways to buy more data : 
1- licences (just do the math because it's or 1GB or licens*
so if you have only 1 license that bring you 20mb your upper bound is 1GB
2- open a case and buy only storage without licenses(should be cheaper)